# align a css timeline component for dynamic data rendering

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to build a timeline component, so the timeline component has majorly 4 components.

1. A cirlce
2. A dotted line
3. left side details
4. right side details

so i am able to add these components, but how to align this so that can be use based on the dynamic data supplied. The text should be there in the left and right side of each circle.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/timeline-component-wxrk6)

[sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMCjK.jpg)

Comment: Your sandbox link is broken

Comment: @GalAbra sorry,  kindly check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I suggest you create your "TimelineEvent" components so they include both the data and the info regarding each event (and receive them as props, obviously).
2. I'd use a table to keep the rows aligned vertically:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.timeline-event {
  height: 100px;
}

.timeline-event:first-of-type .timeline-dash {
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.timeline-event:last-of-type .timeline-dash {
  height: 50%;
}

.middle-cell {
  position: relative;
}

.circle-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: tomato;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.timeline-dash {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr class="timeline-event">
      <td class="data">
        Event Data<br/>
        Second Row
      </td>
      <td class="middle-cell">
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-dash"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="info">
        Event Info
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="timeline-event">
      <td class="data">
        Event Data<br/>
        Second Row<br/>
        Third Row
      </td>
      <td class="middle-cell">
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-dash"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="info">
        Event Info
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="timeline-event">
      <td class="data">
        Event Data<br/> Second Row<br/> Third Row
      </td>
      <td class="middle-cell">
        <div class="circle-wrapper">
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-dash"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="info">
        Event Info
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this approach, i was thinking that if i have a component with left, circle, line and right data as a container so i can do a map and render based on the data and the last container wont have the dotted line

Comment: It's up to you, I just wanted to show that the table was a good approach :)

Comment: how to put the animation so it will look like a drawing line, right now on refresh it wont have any animation. Any idea on this side

Comment: What do you mean? Like the line is drawn from top to bottom?

Comment: now the entire component is shown at load, one by one like something you see in e-commerce websites one by one data loads

Comment: That's a whole new feature, my friend